# Convert Rxjava Completable to Map

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I am need that i will be calling a completable method in the chain, after it completes, it needs to continue the chain with `Map` operator
**Example**

```
Single.just(someOperation())
     .flatMapCompletable{
         completableMethod()
    }
     .map{ // i need to continue here with map or some other operator
         doSomeOperation()
    }
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Completable` does not submit any data. Accordigly you cannot call `map`. If you wan to perform any actions after this use `andThen`

```
Single.just(someOperation())
     .flatMapCompletable{
         completableMethod()
    }
     .andThen{ 
         doSomeOperation()
    }
```

[More about `andThen`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#andThen-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-)